# black diamond question marks- Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, xhtml, markdown, pandoc

I have two rmarkdown generate html reports.

- The first one (rmarkdown version 1.10, pandoc version 2.7.1)with R is working fine
  [image]
- The second one (rmarkdown version 2.2, pandoc version 2.7.1) had black diamond with questions marks show up in places with html characters.
  [image]

I compared the two documents, and it seems that the only differences are in the headings of the html document.

- In the first document, the heading is as following

> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>
> <head>
>
> <meta charset="utf-8" />
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
> ```

- In the second document, the heading is as following

> ```
> <html>
>
> <head>
>
> <meta charset="utf-8" />
> <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
> ```

I am opening both with Chrome. Can someone help explain why this might be happending?

Thank you!

Comment: That question mark character is the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD.

Comment: Is there a reason that Chrome would fail to recognize the utf-8 encoding setting?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with Chrome but that your generated document has invalid utf-8 bytes, which when decoded turn into U+FFFD. Either that or you have literal U+FFFD characters in your document. You can try opening the document in a different browser to see whether the problem is with Chrome or the document.

Comment: also make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in your doc. Using plain pandoc, this is automatically added with the `--standalone` option

Comment: I updated the question to include a bit more information on the header differences. @mb21 Nathan Mills. Thank you for the comments. Do you have additional insights given the updated header information?